# What are the benefits of using IdentityServer4 to connect to AzureAD instead of just going directly to AzureAD?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

Need to authentication and authorize (based on roles and security groups from AzureAD) various web clients and api resources.  Considering relaying this via IdentityServer4 to AzureAD vs direct authentication against AzureAD.  Are there benefits to using IdentityServer4 as a relaying station?

The various clients are ASP.Net Core web, and web api, and reactjs (and possibly angular) spa web applications.

We need to authenticate and authorize the web clients using application level roles as well as security groups downloaded from AzureAD.

Comment: Well, if you go directly to Azure AD your application is tied to that particular option. If you want, later on to introduce Google Authentication, for instance, you are in a bad place. Identity Server acts as a central authentication place, and you can use it as well to protected your APIs, using the multiple OAuth flows available. Side note also: Neither Identity Server or AzureAD are suitable for Authorization. Your applicaton is responsible for authorization, not those two. They *could* return claims and you can use those for authorization but.. it's not really recommended.

Comment: Though note that introducing IdentityServer means extra complexity as well. If it isn't immediately obvious that more providers will be needed and shared across apps, I wouldn't want to take the dependency. "Build it twice right" etc.

Comment: Yes, of course. If it's not needed then there's no point in introducing yet another component.

Comment: jpgrassi: you mention that one could use IDS4 to protect APIs... does this mean that this cannot be easily done directly against AzureAD?

Comment: Also, what is meant by the application is responsible for authorization?  We are returning claims from AzureAD and using those for authorization, but if this is not recommended then what is purely in-app option for authorization?  Local database to store roles and groups?